# "Central Directory Corrupt" on Project Create in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

VS2015 on Windows 10 has been working fine.
But now, when I attempt to create a new solution with its initial project in VS 2015, the Create fails with that error in a dialog box; no other information.
I've tried (i) repairing VS, (ii) changed project location directories, and (iii) checked the disk.
The only references to "Central Directory Corrupt" that I can find seem concerned with operations on zip files, which don't appear relevant.
I guess the next step is to delete and reinstall VS, but thought someone may have a cleverer idea.

Comment: "Central directory corrupt" is the kind of message that's generated by an unzip utility.  That shoe fits, project templates are stored in .zip files.  You ought to be concerned about the health of your disk drive.  Nothing anybody here can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the issue.  As Hans (and I) noted, this is a compressed file problem.
But more particularly, it's a Nuget issue.  Nuget appears to throw this kind of error (vague and not helpful, as they note: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/402) if it gets into a bad state.
It would have been nice if there was some indication that it was a Nuget issue.
Reinstalling Nuget didnt help, nor did repairing VS
And the disk is fine.
What did help was (i) uninstalling Nuget; (ii) deleting every compressed file that I could find for Nuget (notably the cab files), and (iii) reinstalling Nuget. Not an elegant solution - I'm sure that I over deleted - but a brute force one, and not one that i'd recommend - i'm putting it here just to indicate where the problem is.